# Why my renderTitles function does not render a list using map?

Tags: reactjs

My function renderTitles is supposed to output many bootstrap cards with title from an array that i got from an API. I have tested before and the array is there and all its data. The problem is when i call renderTitles function it does not output anything.

I have tried many map function examples and none have worked

```
renderTitles = () => {
  return this.state.popularMovies.map(t => {
    return (
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card" style={{ width: "12rem" }}>
          <div class="card-body">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/iflq7ZJfso6WC7gk9l1tD3unWK.jpg"
            />
            <h5 class="card-title">t.title</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
};
```

It is expected to output all titles inside bootstrap cards with one title each.

Comment: First of all, it should be `{t.title}` instead of `t.title`. Other than that, can we see how do you use this function in your component? How do you set your state, how do you call `renderTitles` etc.

Comment: return(
      <div>
      <h3>Popular Movies</h3>
      {this.renderTitles}

      </div>
    )

Comment: So, just check @Josh Reep's answer. You should invoke it like `{this.renderTitles()}`. Right now you are just using its reference there.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the data that you want to print in `{}` for example:

```
<h5 class="card-title">
    {t.title}
</h5>
```

Also: when you call your `renderTitles` function, make sure that is wrapped in `{}` as well:

```
<div class="all-my-titles">
    {this.renderTitles()}
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted. Just, it probably should be `{this.renderTitles()}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps

```
renderTitles = () =>{
  return  this.state.popularMovies.map((t)=>(
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card" style={{width: '12rem'}}>
            <div class="card-body">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/iflq7ZJfso6WC7gk9l1tD3unWK.jpg"/>
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    {t.title}
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wrap both output of `renderTitles` and `t.title` in `{}`.

[Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)